# ACPI BIOS Error (bug) error logs in kernal.log Ubuntu-20.10

Tags: kernel, acpi

I am using Ubuntu 20.10
My device memory got full in just 10 days from 250 GB to 100 GB
when i looked into logs i found **kern.log** file had a storage of about 50 GB
I looked into many solutions but none of them seems to be working for me .
I get errors like below

```
eb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.226498] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_L6F]
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.226499] No Arguments are initialized for method [_L6F]
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.226500] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._L6F due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.226504] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L6F] (20200528/evgpe-511)
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.228423] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_GPE._L6F.PGRT], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/psargs-330)
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.228428] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_L6F]
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.228428] No Arguments are initialized for method [_L6F]
Feb  3 17:09:07 vikram-singh kernel: [ 1252.228430] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_GPE._L6F due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
```

Kernal which I use **5.8.0-41-generic**
Can someone help in resolving these so it won't get added to log files
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Device memory? You mean hard drive space?

Comment: Yes @David desktop(PC) storage space